# Skip files in Metric_fu Analysis

Tags: ruby, metric-fu

Is it possible to ignore some of my files (i.e. lib/*) in reports generated by metric_fu?

I searched in the [docs](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/metricfu/metric_fu/MetricFu/Configuration) and others soucers and found nothing but to exclude metrics from being generated, not files from being skipped in analysis.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MetricFu maintainer here.  There's currently no way to do that, besides any metric-specific configuration.  However, since the reports break down by file, we could add a config to remove those records from the report. Would that be what you want?  Otherwise, if you mean a global ignore 'lib*', that might be possible in per-metric configs in addition to the previous suggestion.

Comment: I could not find that metric-specific configuration for each one. Do you know some source for that information? Can it be done via .metrics file? Also, removing records in metrif_fu couls also be useful! BTW, my team is starting to use Metric_fu and it's really great! Thank you for the nice work!

Comment: Thanks.   Please create a feature request issue in the metric_fu tracker and maybe post it to the mailing list.

Comment: As stated by @BF4, there currently no way to achieve that. Related issue open: https://github.com/metricfu/metric_fu/issues/256